# CSS Display Background on Mobile

Tags: ios, css, mobile, background, background-image

I've been working with this CSS for a while now, and I thought it's time I ask someone more knowledgeable. I'm semi-new to web-development for mobile platforms, brand new to StackOverflow (created an account just now, but frequent reader beforehand), and I'm trying to figure my way around this.

Basically, my background image shows in the browser on my PC, but not in the mobile browser. I would really appreciate help!

If you would like to see screenshots, I've uploaded pictures to a Dropbox public link:

Rendering on Google Chrome, Mac OSX: [PC Rendering](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/43717161/StackOverflow/OSXScreen.png)

Rendering on Safari, iOS: [Mobile Rendering](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/43717161/StackOverflow/iOSScreen.png)

```
body {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 24px;
    color: #626262;
    height: 100%;
    background: #fff url('default-bg.jpg') center center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

.tall-header-page,
.short-header-page,
.no-header-page,
.landing-page {
    background: #222121;
}

.tall-header-page .wsite-background,
.short-header-page .wsite-background{
    background: #fff url('image123.jpg') center center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.landing-page .wsite-background {
    background: #fff url('default-bg.jpg') center center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Thank you, and if I haven't provided enough code, please let me know!

Comment: Your second link is sending to the same picture as first link. Couldn't tell a difference between them and then realized it's because it's the same image.

Comment: Ah! I apologize, I fixed it now!

Comment: have you tried giving the `.wsite-background` element a pixel height?

Comment: If you want it to stretch the full height maybe use the following on .ws-background: `position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;` to force it to stretch to the whole viewport. This would mean you need to `position: relative;` the navigation element and set it's `z-index` higher the the background. Hard to tell what you are trying to achieve without a jsfiddle.